# Xcode 6 Autolayout Constraints: Making button not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am making an app where you take a picture and cannot see it until you click "view picture." The app works great. I added missing constraints for all views, and it looks great across all devices. However, after I added the constraints, the "take picture" button does not work anymore.

When constraints are added and I click the "take picture" button: all of the buttons disappear and the text changes to landscape instead of portrait.

I have no idea why the constraints would change the actual function of the "take picture" button? 
If anyone could explain why this is happening that would be very helpful.

Below is my code for taking the picture in case that is the problem.

```
AVCaptureSession *session;

AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];


    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];

    if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
        [session addInput:deviceInput];

    }

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    CGRect frame = self.frameForCapture.frame;

    [previewLayer setFrame:frame];

    [rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];

}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {

    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer !=NULL) {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            self.imageView.image = image;
        }
    }];


}
```

Comment: you need to show your constraints as well

Comment: Is there a way to copy and paste a list of the constraints?

Comment: if you have added the constraints in storyboard, simply add the screenshot

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having a similar issue where my button is displayed fine until it is clicked.  When clicked I get an error saying that the constraints can no longer be satisfied.

Comment: No I could never figure it out